# ltablex hack in LatexML?

Tags: tables, longtable, ltablex, mathml, latexml

I need to access to `ltablex`-like functionality within the confines of the packages available to LatexML. Namely, a long table that needs to have wrapped text in columns. Ordinarily, I'd do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\label{lab:aLabel}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
\caption{A caption.}
\toprule
A & Some long stuff that needs to wrap.
B & More stuff that needs to wrap.
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

, but LatexML doesn't support ltablex. Any alternative to pasting all of `ltablex.sty` into my preamble?

Comment: I should have specified, I am writing using Authorea, which is a collaborative writing environment that uses LatexML for it's backend. Editing is done in a web interface, but can export to PDF using LaTex (MathML? I'm not sure what's going on under the hood.).

Comment: yes but surely the non math parts like section headings and tables get converted to _html_ not mathml so you just want a an html table don't you? why do you need MathML mtable support?

Comment: Irrespective of how the table shows up in the browser, I need the PDF output to behave as if  I'm using `ltablex`.  [Here](https://support.authorea.com/en-us/article/how-do-i-include-a-latex-package-1bjtigr/) is a relevant post from the Authorea knowledge base. I hadn't even thought of making a html table, but I don't know if it's possible through the web interface. The primary method of making advanced tables on that platform is through LaTex.

Comment: Well, I'm asking how to make a table withing the confines of a certain set of packages I'm allowed to use, namely, those supported by MathML..

Comment: do you mean "supported by latexml" ?  asking if a latex package is supported by mathml does not make sense mathml does not support any latex package they are just unrelated.

Comment: The post I linked to itself links to that list of packages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93210/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-mark).

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remind is to make the need known to the latexml developers (hi!) and request support at the [LaTeXML issue tracker](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues), so that we know there is interest for `ltablex`.

If you think latexml can successfully natively interpret that package you can add the `--includestyles` option and have it pick the raw `.sty` file from your TeX distribution. And if it fails, that is a great addition to a new issue requesting that we add support.